# Enable horizontal scrolling Phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is it possible to enable horizontal scrolling in `Phpstorm`?

I have found nothing whilst searching through the settings.

Comment: Do you mean with the mouse wheel or pad? If so .. then unfortunately it's not possible -- JDK does not support it (maybe in v9). https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-81013

Comment: argh godd stuff, I did mean with the mouse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my particular case it was that I was running `autohotkey` which had something bound to shift... So phpstorm couldn't pick up on it.

Answer (score 59):

Have you tried holding  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + mouse scrolling?

I tested it from version 8.0.3 up to 9.0.2 and it works just fine.

**Bonus hint**:
This feature is actually pretty standard on many programs. Even on you browser, if you zoom-in right now so that the horizontal scroll bar appears, and try to scroll while holding <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, it will side scroll.

Comment: Must be a mac setting :'( Oh how I wish I could sideways scroll

Comment: @JamieHutber I use Windows and Ubuntu and it works on both.

Comment: In my phpstorm, by holding SHIFT + mouse scrolling go to  last right side. How can i do slower scroll

Comment: @karim_fci On Windows, check your mouse settings.

Comment: Hi.
Is is possible to change the  SHIFT + mouse   to   CTRL + mouse ??
Thanks.

Comment: On this website, no, since it's too responsively built :D

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it's not possible to perform horizontal scroll with mouse (mouse wheel) or pads -- JDK does not support it (maybe in v9).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-81013

Comment: you can. hold down shift.